# Java: Read a text file with Points stored in Arrays and draw Points on an image

Tags: java, arrays, point

I don't know how to do that. I've got a text file with a coordinates stored as a Points in an array. Every new array is a new object to draw. It looks like this:

> [{1413.0, 1741.0}, {1413.0, 1757.0}, {1412.0, 1758.0}, {1412.0, 1784.0}, {1413.0, 1785.0}, {1413.0, 1788.0}]
>   [{3136.0, 1644.0}, {3135.0, 1645.0}, {3132.0, 1645.0}, {3131.0, 1646.0}, {3130.0, 1646.0}, {3128.0, 1648.0}, {3128.0, 1649.0}, {3127.0, 1650.0}, {3127.0, 1653.0}, {3126.0, 1654.0}, {3126.0, 1656.0}, {3127.0, 1657.0}, {3127.0, 1660.0}, {3128.0, 1661.0}, {3128.0, 1662.0}, {3131.0, 1665.0}, {3132.0, 1665.0}, {3133.0, 1666.0}, {3136.0, 1666.0}, {3137.0, 1667.0}, {3138.0, 1667.0}, {3139.0, 1666.0}, {3142.0, 1666.0}, {3143.0, 1665.0}, {3144.0, 1665.0}, {3147.0, 1662.0}, {3147.0, 1661.0}, {3148.0, 1660.0}, {3148.0, 1657.0}, {3149.0, 1656.0}, {3149.0, 1654.0}, {3148.0, 1653.0}, {3148.0, 1650.0}, {3147.0, 1649.0}, {3147.0, 1648.0}, {3145.0, 1646.0}, {3144.0, 1646.0}, {3143.0, 1645.0}, {3140.0, 1645.0}, {3139.0, 1644.0}]

Every next array is by the new line, one array have many points, but ofcourse every array is not the same, they don't have the same length and parameters.

I've already converted from a text file to a String loading it by the nextlines, but I don't know how to show a program to draw a shape on that coordinates like for example: {3143.0, 1645.0}. Could you help me?

Edit: I think that the best way is to convert that huge String to a

```
List<Points>
```

that would be great.

Greetings, Rafał

Comment: This is looking like [tag:json]. You should try parsing this text with a json library.

Comment: Question has two parts, both already asked before, search Read file in Java and draw Points in Canvas using java

Comment: Show us the code how you read your file.